# Handle chunked data sent by Play scala with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework-2.2, chunked, http-chunked

I send `chunked data` with `Play Scala 2.2` to the client side like this : `Ok.chunked(data)`

I would like to use them as soon as they are available on the client side. If I just get the data and print them on `.success`, they are printed at the same time i.e. when the last data is received.

How can I print them as soon as they are received? Must I use `websockets`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use streaming json library like http://oboejs.com/

Oboe.js is an open source Javascript library for loading JSON using streaming, combining the convenience of DOM with the speed and fluidity of SAX.

It can parse any JSON as a stream, is small enough to be a micro-library, doesn’t have dependencies, and doesn’t care which other libraries you need it to speak to.

Comment: Looks great, I'm going to take a look at it, thanks ;)