# Angular $http service returns empty string for large JSON response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, large-data

A data intensive intranet application uses the  following `angularjs` post function. It calls a Web API service returning a large JSON object in a chunked stream. This works perfectly well for responses of 100Mb but fails when the response reaches about 250 Mb.

```
$scope.refresh = function (){
        usSpinnerService.spin("main-grid");
        $http.post('/api/Assets/GetLargeJSONResult', $scope.postPayload
            ).then(
                function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.mainGridOptions.api.setRowData(response.data);
                    $scope.mainGridOptions.api.refreshView();
                    clearErrorMessage();
            },
            httpErrorCallback)
            .then(refreshGridTwo)
            .finally(function () {
                usSpinnerService.stop("main-grid");
            });
};
```

Putting a breakpoint on the line `$scope.mainGridOptions.api.setRowData(response.data);` shows that  `response.data` is an empty string.

Everything else works fine. I've tried various different ways of returning the JSON response from the web server and so I doubt the problem is on the server end. I'm targeting the Chrome browser in Windows.

Relevant request headers:

> - Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> - Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> - Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
> - Connection: keep-alive

Relevant response headers

> - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> - Cache-Control: no-cache
> - Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> - Content-Type: application/json
> - Expires: -1

I know one option would be to page the response into smaller chunks. However, I would prefer to keep the data intact as it's being analysed in a grid. I wondered if I'm missing something as I can successfully stream very large open office xml files (media type "application/octet-stream") to the browser from Web API without any issues.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28710394/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22103927/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23181492/215552

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint where it actually returns the value in web api to make sure its serializing correctly? I've hit a point where it returns but hits a serialization error.

Comment: Dylan, There are no serialization errors. It returns correctly for objects of the same type but around 100Mb. It's due to the size. The similar questions posted by Mike (thanks!) all point to consuming the stream one chunk at a time, but there doesn't seem to be a simple 'angular' way of doing it.

Comment: Possibly a limit  set by the web server. Have you tried accessing the data using an external tool such as `curl`, `wget`, etc.?

Comment: Check the value set for `maxAllowedContentLength` in your web.config. You can also check this link: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Update on 'progress' so far: I used oboe.js to parse the streamed result with some success in that I can at least see that the data arriving one batch at a time. If I push the results into an array, I still get an 'aw snap' out of memory error in Chrome even though I use oboe's  oboe.drop; method. Perhaps 200Mb is just too much data in one array for Chrome? At least this rules out the server as the problem.

Comment: This seems to be relevant... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043725/loading-large-json-files-250mb-with-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402716/handle-xmlhttprequest-response-with-large-data

Comment: In Chrome 85 XMLHttpRequest#response returns "null" and no error event is fired when loading >512MB json.
Fetch API (with Response#json()) throws an error with confusing message "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".
This looks like a browser bug.